# modelling trees or graphs SQL: how to separate properties of nodes and nodes information

Tags: sql, graph, tree

I'm modelling a conceptual ontology like a [polytree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree).

Using the [edge list model](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html#edge_list) it would be:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes(
  nodeID CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE edges(
  childID CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  parentID CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(childID,parentID)
);
```

My problem is how can I model it in SQL so that nodes can have other properties like "types". Eg.

```
(father-node) **Music**
```

has

```
(child-node) **jazz** [type: genre], **soul** [type: genre]
(child-node) **concert** [type: performed], **DJ set** [type: performed]
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to stackoverflow! is it now fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out Celkos nested set model, http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

But anyway just add genre id to your nodes table

```
CREATE TABLE nodes(
  nodeID CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY
  genre_id
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm having difficulties with Celkos model because I need something like a polytree (one node can have more than one father)

Comment: OK, then celko won't work, but adding genre_id to your node table should , unless the genre is dependent on the parent-child relationship, i.e. the node is genreA when child of parent A , but genreB when child of parent B, then the genre_id would need to be in your edges table